# ReactJS 0.12.2: Is 'key' gone forever from a component?

Tags: reactjs

We use to have `this.props.key`. We still have `key` in the ReactElement, but apparently not in the component object itself, i.e., we cannot access the key through `this` in a life-cycle method. Is this true? I can see that if I create an element, I could do something like:

```
<MyComponent key={theKey} myKey={theKey} ...>
```

and I would be able to access `theKey` value in a life-cycle method as `this.props.myKey`, but what if I do not create the element? Is there a way to find what the key was in the element through the component itself?

Answer (score 3):

From the [official blog](http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2014/10/16/react-v0.12-rc1.html#breaking-change-key-and-ref-removed-from-this.props):

> You can no longer access this.props.ref and this.props.key from inside
>   the Component instance itself. So you need to use a different name for
>   those props.

Answer (score 0):

<s>You can still access key from inside the component, it's just been moved from this.props.key to this.key</s>

Nope, nope you can't..

> We made this distinction clearer by moving them off the props object
>   and onto the ReactElement itself. This means that you need to rename:
>
> **someElement.props.key -> someElement.key**

Comment: so, which one is it? Cannot get to the key anymore (like @nilgun) says, or can get it on `this`?

Comment: It's @nilgun who's right, you cannot access the key from inside the component, the new syntax is for getting it from the outside.